# Disable all notifications in Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, notification-area

Is there a way to disable **all** notifications in Ubuntu 16/18/20?
When I disable them in settings some notifications still pop up like Crash Reports.
I tried to use the tool NoNotifications (nonotifs) but it crashes on running it.

I am trying to run Ubuntu as a base for a kiosk system which runs a web browser to present content.